Hibernate not creating tables using SQLite with HikariCP
I have got 2 datasources.

Postgres database
SQLite database

I want to store different data in postgres and in sqlite.
The problem is that hibernate does not create tables the way it does in postgres. In postgres all tables are created / updated. In SQLite nothing gets created ☹️
I managed to make it work but I cannot bypass this error:
Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: settings)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1179) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1190) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:1150) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:132) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:264) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.<init>(CorePreparedStatement.java:46) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:32) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:25) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC4Connection.java:34) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:225) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:205) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.45.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:327) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]

Datasource bean class content:
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = ["io.myapp.jvmbackend.repository.jpa.sqlite"],
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "sqliteEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "sqliteTransactionManager",
    bootstrapMode = BootstrapMode.DEFAULT
)
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true, mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
open class SQLiteDatasourceConfiguration(@Autowired(required = true) private val appInfo: AppInfo) {


    @Bean(name = ["SQLiteDataSource"])
    open fun sqliteDataSource(): HikariDataSource {
        val ddlAuto = if(appInfo.production) {
            "update"
        } else if(appInfo.staging){
            "update"
        } else {
            "create"
        }

        val dialect = "org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect"
        val driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC"
        val url = "jdbc:sqlite:myapp.db"


        val sqLiteConfig = SQLiteConfig()

        sqLiteConfig.transactionMode = SQLiteConfig.TransactionMode.EXCLUSIVE
        sqLiteConfig.enforceForeignKeys(false)
        sqLiteConfig.setEncoding(SQLiteConfig.Encoding.UTF_8)
        sqLiteConfig.setPragma(SQLiteConfig.Pragma.JOURNAL_MODE,JournalMode.WAL.value)
        sqLiteConfig.setSynchronous(SQLiteConfig.SynchronousMode.FULL)
        sqLiteConfig.setUserVersion(1)

        val jpaProperties = sqLiteConfig.toProperties()
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", ddlAuto)
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", ddlAuto)
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show-sql", appInfo.developer)
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", false)
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect)
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys", true)

        val hikariConfig = HikariConfig()
        hikariConfig.jdbcUrl = url
        hikariConfig.driverClassName = driver
        hikariConfig.poolName = "${appInfo.name}SqliteHikariPool".replace(" ","")
        hikariConfig.maxLifetime = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)
        hikariConfig.idleTimeout = 100
        hikariConfig.keepaliveTime = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(4)
        hikariConfig.maximumPoolSize = 2
        hikariConfig.minimumIdle = 0
        hikariConfig.leakDetectionThreshold = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2)
        hikariConfig.connectionTimeout = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)
        hikariConfig.isAutoCommit = true

        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", true)
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", true)
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", 500)
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", 1024)
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("rewriteBatchedStatements", true)

        hikariConfig.dataSourceProperties = jpaProperties

        return HikariDataSource(hikariConfig)
    }
    @Bean(name = ["sqliteEntityManagerFactory"])
    open fun sqliteEntityManagerFactoryBean(
        builder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
        @Qualifier("SQLiteDataSource") qaDataSource: DataSource
    ): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        return builder.dataSource(qaDataSource)
            .packages("io.myapp.jvmbackend.data.model.sqlite")
            .persistenceUnit("sqlite").build()
    }

    @Bean(name = ["sqliteTransactionManager"])
    open fun sqliteTransactionManager(@Qualifier("sqliteEntityManagerFactory") entityManager: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean): PlatformTransactionManager {
        return JpaTransactionManager(entityManager.getObject())
    }
} 

Settings entity:
@Entity(name = "settings")
@Table(name = "settings", indexes = [Index(name = "settings_index_name", columnList = "name")])
open class Setting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SettingId")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "SettingId",
        strategy = "io.myapp.jvmbackend.data.idGenerator.SqliteDBIdentifierGenerator"
    )
    @Column(
        name = "id",
        columnDefinition = "TEXT",
        updatable = false,
        insertable = true,
        nullable = false,
        unique = true
    )
    open var id: String = ""

    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition="TEXT", updatable = true, insertable = true, nullable = false, unique = false)
    @Convert(converter = SettingNameConverter::class)
    open var name: SettingName = SettingName.API_REQUEST_HANDLER_THREADS_COUNT

    @Column(name = "value", updatable = true, insertable = true, nullable = true, unique = false)
    open var value: String? = null

    @Column(name = "isProduction", updatable = true, insertable = true, nullable = false, unique = false)
    open var isProduction: Boolean = false

    @Column(name = "createdAt", updatable = true, insertable = true, nullable = false, unique = false)
    open var createdAt: Long = 0

    @Column(name = "updatedAt", updatable = true, insertable = true, nullable = true, unique = false)
    open var updatedAt: Long? = null

    constructor(){
        this.createdAt = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }

    constructor(
        name: SettingName,
        isProduction: Boolean,
        value: String
    ) : this() {
        this.name = name
        this.isProduction = isProduction
        this.value = value
        this.createdAt = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Setting

        if (id != other.id) return false
        if (name != other.name) return false
        if (value != other.value) return false
        if (isProduction != other.isProduction) return false
        if (createdAt != other.createdAt) return false
        if (updatedAt != other.updatedAt) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + (value?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        result = 31 * result + isProduction.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + createdAt.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + (updatedAt?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        return result
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Setting(id=$id, name=$name, value=$value, isProduction=$isProduction, createdAt=$createdAt, updatedAt=$updatedAt)"
    }
}

I am getting entityManager like this for sqlite datasource:
    @Autowired(required = true)
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sqlite")
    private lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

How can I fix this issue so Hibernate will create all tables in SQLite database ?
